# Getting error when appending to documentFragment

Tags: jquery

I'm getting an error when creating a document fragment, appending elements to it and returning that fragment. I've used document fragments in the past (abused them way beyond this example) and have never run in to this error. In the developer console it lists this as the source of the error:

```
fragment.appendChild($balanceNumber, $balanceSign);
```

**Error**

> Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

**Function**

```
var constructBalanceFragment = function(balance) {
    var $balanceNumber, $balanceSign, fragment, sign;
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    $balanceNumber = $('<span class="balance_number"></span>');
    $balanceSign = $('<span class="balance_sign"></span>');
    if (balance > 0) {
      sign = "+";
      $balanceSign.addClass("positive_number");
    } else if (balance < 0) {
      sign = "-";
      $balanceSign.addClass("negative_number");
    } else {
      sign = "";
    }
    $balanceNumber.text(balance);
    $balanceSign.text(sign);
    fragment.appendChild($balanceNumber, $balanceSign);
    return fragment;
```

**Edit**

I have tried this and still got the same error before anyone asks

```
fragment.appendChild($balanceNumber);
fragment.appendChild($balanceSign);
```

Comment: `$balanceNumber` is a jQuery object, not a node. And `.appendChild()` accepts only one argument.

Comment: I've appended jquery objects to a document fragment and never have had an issue.

Comment: Looking through old code it looks like in the past I've done `$object.appendTo(fragment)`. Does that really make a difference? I'll test and update

Comment: `.appendTo()` is a jQuery method, which is operating on (presumably) a jQuery object. Apparently jQuery will accept a document fragment as the container, though it doesn't seem to be explicitly supported according to the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is closer to your original and seems to work, keeping it in the spirit of jQuery:

```
$(fragment).append($balanceNumber, $balanceSign);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TfDXD/1/

Comment: I like this even better than my answer. Shorter.

Comment: I tweaked the fiddle so it's actually working with numbers. Duh.

Answer (score 1):

**Work around**

I fixed this by using `$object.appendTo(fragment)` vs `fragment.appendChild($object)` for those running in to this in the future.